# Applications of inverse of Klein's $j$-invariant

Tags: motivation, modular-function

The Klein $j$-invariant
$$j(\tau) = q^{-1} + 744 + 196884q + \cdots$$
is a weight $0$ modular function holomorphic for $\tau$ in the upper-half plane $\mathbb{H}$. I understand that $j$ is important, given that two elliptic curves are isomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if they have the same $j$-invariant.

We know that $j$ is a bijection from the fundamental domain $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \backslash \mathbb{H}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

I am wondering, what are some interesting applications of the inverse $j^{-1}$? What are some situations in which computing $j^{-1}$ of some complex number arises?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the [proof of the little picard theorem using $\lambda^{-1}(\tau)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lambda_function#Little_Picard_theorem). Given that $\lambda$ is closely related to $j$, it could mean you that you get a proof of the little Picard theorem using $j^{-1}$.  Anyway $j^{-1}$ should be useful [in the context of the modularity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_modular_curve#Parametrization_of_the_modular_curve).

Comment: And also, if $f(\tau)$ is modular (i.e. meromorphic $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})\setminus \mathbb{H}\to \mathbb{C}$) then $f(j^{-1}(\tau))$ is meromorphic $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$, and you can apply the  Liouville theorem that a bounded entire function is constant, [obtaining that $j$ generates the function field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_curve#Genus_zero) $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})\setminus \mathbb{H}\to \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: In the theory of Weierstrass elliptic functions, the inverse Klein-j function can be used to get the Weierstrass half-periods from the Weierstrass elliptic invariants.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an inverse of Klein’s Invariant j. First put it [in terms of Modular Lambda](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/KleinInvariantJ/27/02/03/0004/):
$$y=\text j(z)=256 \frac{(\lambda^2(z)-\lambda(z)+1)^3}{\lambda^2(z)(1-\lambda(z))^2}$$

Now put the Modular Lambda function [in terms of the Inverse Nome](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/ModularLambda/27/01/03/):

$$256 \frac{(\lambda^2(z)-\lambda(z)+1)^3}{\lambda^2(z)(1-\lambda(z))^2} = 256 \frac{(\text q^{-1}(e^{i\pi z})^2-\text q^{-1}(e^{i\pi z}) +1)^3}{\text q^{-1}(e^{i\pi z})^2(1-\text q^{-1}(e^{i\pi z}))^2} $$

Now invert $256\frac{(y^2-y+1)^3}{y^2(1-y)^2}$ [with radicals like so](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+of+256+%28y%5E2-y%2B1%29%5E3%2F%28y%5E2%281-y%29%5E2%29):

$$\lambda(z)=\text q^{-1}(e^{i\pi z})=\frac12\pm\frac12\sqrt{\frac1{192}\sqrt[3]{y^3-2304y^2+12288\sqrt3\sqrt{1728y^2-y^3}+884736y}-\frac{1536y-y^2}{192\sqrt[3]{y^3-2304y^2+12288\sqrt3\sqrt{1728y^2-y^3}+884736y}}+\frac y{192}-3}$$

Therefore, two branches with the [Elliptic Integral $\text K(k)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=EllipticK) are:

$$\text j^{-1}(z)=i\frac{\text K\left(\frac12\mp\frac12\sqrt{\frac1{192}\sqrt[3]{z^3-2304z^2+12288\sqrt3\sqrt{1728z^2-z^3}+884736z}-\frac{1536z-z^2}{192\sqrt[3]{z^3-2304z^2+12288\sqrt3\sqrt{1728z^2-z^3}+884736z}}+\frac z{192}-3}\right)}{\text K\left(\frac12\pm\frac12\sqrt{\frac1{192}\sqrt[3]{z^3-2304z^2+12288\sqrt3\sqrt{1728z^2-z^3}+884736z}-\frac{1536z-z^2}{192\sqrt[3]{z^3-2304z^2+12288\sqrt3\sqrt{1728z^2-z^3}+884736z}}+\frac z{192}-3}\right)}$$

where $-,+$ or $+,-$ is taken. Hopefully there are no typos.

Answer (score 0):

If $g_2$ and $g_3$ are the Weierstrass elliptic invariants, then the corresponding half-periods ratio is given by
$$
\tau = j^{-1}\left(\frac{1728 g_2^3}{g_2^3 - 27 g_3^2}\right)
$$
except in some particular cases.